# Why am I getting an error? (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the amount of rows that `referral_in` and `referral_out` exist in (as separate variables). This is my code for that:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$connect = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx!") or die("Couldnt Connect to Server");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die("Couldnt find database");

$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WERE `username`=$username");
$same = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

$leadcheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_out` FROM `users` WERE `username`=$username");
$leading = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
echo "$leading / $same"
```

When do it, I am getting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/50/8492150/html/buyarandom/member.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/50/8492150/html/buyarandom/member.php on line 25
```

Comment: Unless $username is a numeric value or a boolean, it needs to be quoted - the drawbacks of ___not___ using MySQLi or PDO and prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the quotes around `$username`

```
$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WERE `username`='".$username."'");
```

Also try to escape the `$username` as you are code is vulnerable towards `SQL Injection`

```
$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WERE `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'");
```

**SIDE NOTE:** Don't use `mysql_query` instead use `mysqli`

```
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

$samecheck instead of $namecheck??? Where is $namecheck defined?

Answer (score 0):

First off, `mysql` extension is deprecated. Please [consider MySqli or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Second, you may want to sanitize your session variable for security reasons. If you use a parameterized query with MySQLi or PDO, you have nothing to worry about. Otherwise, the APIs provide methods ([mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) to escape your string.

Now there's a typo in `WERE`, should be `WHERE`.

If `username` is a string type, you need to enclose the value in quotes.

```
$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
$same = mysql_num_rows($samecheck); //another typo; should be $samecheck
```

Also in your second `mysql_num_rows()`, you probably meant to pass `$leadcheck`, not `$namecheck`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$connect = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx!") or die("Couldn't Connect to Server");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die("Couldn't find database");

$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=$username") or die (mysql_error());
$same = mysql_num_rows($samecheck);

$leadcheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_out` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=$username") or die (mysql_error());
$leading = mysql_num_rows($leadcheck);
echo "$leading / $same"
```

also, please at some point consider using mysqli

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

because the mysql extension is deprecated, open to SQL injection, and will likely be removed in a newer version of PHP

Comment: I did what you suggested and it got rid of the error. Now it is giving me this:
    Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'
(Username is the actual username)

Comment: I think MySQL is case sensitive. You need to give it the EXACT column name you store usernames in, including the correct capitalisation

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      $username = $_SESSION['username'];

   $connect = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx!") or die("Couldnt Connect to Server");
   mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die("Couldnt find database");

   $samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` ,`referral_out`  FROM `users` WHERE `username`=$username");
   $same = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($samecheck);

  echo $row['referral_in'] / $row['referral_out'] ;
```

note:

- mysql is decprecated , please use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying that $namecheck is not a mysql_query.
$namecheck is not defined.

$namecheck should be $namecheck and $leadcheck respectively.

```
$samecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_in` FROM `users` WERE `username`=$username");
$same = mysql_num_rows($samecheck);

$leadcheck = mysql_query("SELECT `referral_out` FROM `users` WERE `username`=$username");
$leading = mysql_num_rows($leadcheck);
```